# Azure WebApp multi-container configuration corrupted

Tags: azure, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service, azure-web-app-for-containers

After a code change our web-app went down. Inspection revealed this seems to be caused by an invalid docker compose definition, which lives in a separate repository and was not affected by this change. When I look at the configuration in the portal, I see a garbled / corrupted docker compose file. Triggering a release did not resolve the issue. Modifying the docker compose file (adding a dummy env var, jus to make sure it has a different hash) did not fix the issue. The compose file is using UTF-8 encoded.

I've tried retrieving the image using `az webapp config container show --resource-group [RG]--name [NAME] --slot [SLOT]`. This gives me an env var "DOCKER_CUSTOM_IMAGE_NAME" which starts with "COMPOSE|" and a base64 string behind that.

When I try to decode this string the output is corrupted as well.

I've tried switching to a single container image. This shows the env var being "DOCKER|[image-name]". Triggering a release after that results in corrupted output again.

This problem seems similar to the one described here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1096679/compose-file-corrupted-in-release-task.html

Has anyone else experienced this error? If so, how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have been bitten by a bug in the Azure CLI: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/14208